# Deploying a Firebase function from a firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a main firebase function. Inside this function I want programmatically deploy another firebase function inside the same project. The code of this new firebase function can be stored someone in a zip file? I don't know the exact code! preferably I want to do this in NodeJS.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

This use case is not supported by Firebase or Google Cloud.  I won't say that it's impossible, but you will have to reverse engineer the APIs used for deployment, and make use of them directly, and I suspect it will be a lot of work.  Since the Firebase CLI is [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools), it would be a good idea to look there first to see how deployment works.

Since this situation isn't really supported and requires a lot of effort, I suggesting finding another way of solving the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also not possible to create a function/script somewhere with the firebase CLI installed and deploy it from there automatically?

Comment: You can certainly script the deployment of functions to run on another machine that has the deployment tools installed.

Comment: Is is possible do to do this with Google Cloud build?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it.  But I don't think it's going to do anything special for you.